# c++ application cannot find com dll because compiler generating .tlh file with incorrect guids

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, com

I have a com dll that gets used in a c++ project. I have not registered the dll but its in the same solution. My application continuously breaks and I found that it breaks here

```
hr = CoCreateInstance(rclsid, pOuter, dwClsContext, __uuidof(IUnknown), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pIUnknown));
```

because I don't have a com class with that guid (rclsid). I did more digging and I found that it gets the guid from a .tlh file in a temp directory but the guid differs from my code.

.tlh file

```
    struct __declspec(uuid("b10a18c8-7109-3f48-94d9-e48b526fc928"))
    DocMapEntry;
    // [ default ] interface _DocMapEntry
    // interface _Object
    // interface IDocMapEntry
```

c# code (com visable dll)

```
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("E98676B9-1965-4248-A9B6-74EC5EE5385A")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
    public interface IDocMapEntry
    {
        int Offset { get; set; }
        int PageOffset { get; set; }
        int PageNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

I tried changing the value to the correct value but it continuously gets changed and visual studio asks me to reload.

When I look at the class using com explorer I get a different clsid, and when I try to unregister it, it completes successfully but the item is still there and the file location is mscoree.

my c++ application uses the guid in the .tlh file but doesn't find the file.

```
public class DocMapEntry : IDocMapEntry
 {
   ...
 }
```

My questions are.

Do I need to register my com dll for this to work?
how can I set the guid for the class?
Why would it create a temp .tlh file with the wrong guid? (optional)
why can't I change this file? (optional)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 public interface IDocMapEntry
```

COM strongly distinguishes between a CLSID and a IID.  The IID, the interface identifier, identifies an interface implemented by a COM object.  We can see that one, you specified it with the [Guid] attribute.  You'd pass it as the 4th argument of CoCreateInstance(), the one where you now pass the IID of IUnknown.

What you need is the CLSID, the class identifier.  We can't see it in your snippet, it is the one for whatever *class* implements your IDocMapEntry.  With some odds that it is named DocMapEntry.  And additional odds that you didn't give it a [Guid] so the CLR will auto-generate one for you.  Note that it will *change* when you modify the class, one possible reason for CoCreateObject() to fail.

Forgetting to register the .NET assembly with Regasm.exe /codebase is another reason, you stated as much in your question.  This is required or COM will not be able to find the DLL and fails the call with error code 0x80040154, "Class not registered".  Having it in the same solution is **not** sufficient, COM search rules are not anything like those used by .NET.

Also note that you are exposing the internals of the class, avoid that by applying the [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)] attribute on the class.

Comment: Hi I added the class signature to my question. how can I set a clsid for the class?

Comment: With a [Guid] attribute, just like you did for the interface.  And like I mentioned in the answer.  And you use __uuidof() in your C++ code as well so it doesn't actually matter that you use a [Guid].

Comment: I added the guid attribute to my class signature and it works. I set the guid to the value in the .tlh file

Answer (score 1):

No you do not have to register the COM DLL but you do need to register an object responsible for creating the COM objects. Use do this in your application by calling [`CoRegisterClassObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693407%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) after the COM subsystem has been initialized (by calling [`CoInitialize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`CoInitializeEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695279%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

```
IClassFactory *factory = new ObjectFactory();

// Register the factory responsible for creating our COM objects
DWORD classToken;
HRESULT hr = CoRegisterClassObject(
    Object_CLSIID,
    factory,
    CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER,
    REGCLS_MULTIPLEUSE,
    &classToken);

// Now we can create the objects
Object *obj = nullptr;
hr = CoCreateInstance(
    Object_CLSIID,
    nullptr,
    CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER,
    Object_IID,
    reinterpret_cast<void**>(&obj));
```

Not sure why it's creating a temporary `.tlh` but I suspect it's something in your build settings - possibly in the build steps.

Answer (score 1):

Is your COM object in a C# dll ? If yes, did you run regasm previously in your system, which could have registered the COM dll.

Guid("E98676B9-1965-4248-A9B6-74EC5EE5385A"): This is your interface GUID, not your component guid.

You should have a GUID declared for COM object in the implementation class, which should be b10a18c8-7109-3f48-94d9-e48b526fc928.

Why would it create a temp .tlh file with the wrong guid?

Are you sure you have not imported the COM dll using #import keyword.

Comment: If I register the dll how can I debug it?